Customize a gradetable in the exam class
I would like to customize the look&feel of the exam's gradetable command.
Does anybody know how this could be accomplished? Here is a MWE of how it is supposed to look like:
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}

\RequirePackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, color}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|Q[l,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] |},
    row{1}={bg=lightgray, font=\bfseries\sffamily},
    column{1}={font=\bfseries\sffamily},
    stretch=2
}
\toprule
Task            & 1   & 2   & 3    & 4    & Total & Grade  \\ \hline
Maximum Points  & (5) & (5) & (10) & (30) & (50)   & (1,0) \\ \hline
Earned Points   &     &     &      &      &        &       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\begin{questions}
    \question[5] Example Question 1
    \question[5] Example Question 2
    \question[10] Example Question 3
    \question[30] Example Question 4
\end{questions}

\end{document}

I found this solution here but can't get it to work.


All of the information for the grade table is stored in the aux file (except for Grade, whatever that is).

I finally managed to find and create a solution. I don't know if this is very efficient or even nice looking, but it should be generic enough to be picked up by others if they want to resolve a similar task.
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.08}

\RequirePackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, color}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Create a custom grade table with tabularray
%%% Can be invoked via \createGradingTable
%%% Define a counter for the number of questions
\makeatletter
\newcounter{questionnumber}
% Set counter to number of questions from exam class, default to 1 if undefined
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{questionnumber}{\@ifundefined{exam@numquestions}{1}{\exam@numquestions}}%
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createGradingTable}{}{
  % Initialize table body
  \tl_clear:N \mybody
  \tl_put_right:Nn \mybody { \toprule Task & }
  
  % First row: Question numbers + Total + Grade
  \int_step_inline:nn {\thequestionnumber} {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} = {\thequestionnumber} {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \mybody { ##1 & Total & Grade \\ \midrule Maximum~Points & }
    }{
      \tl_put_right:Nn \mybody { ##1 & }
    }
  }
  
  % Second row: Maximum points for each question
  \int_step_inline:nn {\thequestionnumber} {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} = {\thequestionnumber} {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \mybody { (\pointsofquestion{##1}) & (\numpoints) & (1,0) \\ \midrule Earned~Points }
    }{
      \tl_put_right:Nn \mybody { (\pointsofquestion{##1}) & }
    }
  }
  
  % Final row: Empty cells for earned points
  \tl_put_right:Nn \mybody { & & & & \\ \bottomrule }
  
  % Create table with formatting
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\mybody]{
    colspec = {|Q[l,m] *{\thequestionnumber}{| X[c,m]} | X[c,m] | X[c,m] |},
    row{1}={bg=lightgray, font=\bfseries\sffamily},  % Header row styling
    column{1}={font=\bfseries\sffamily},             % First column styling
    stretch=2
  }
  \mybody
  \end{tblr}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\createGradingTable

\begin{questions}
    \question[5] Example Question 1
    \question[5] Example Question 2
    \question[10] Example Question 3
    \question[15] Example Question 4
    \question[15] Example Question 5
\end{questions}

\end{document}


